# Facebook user account remains empty in iOS settings after using Facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using ACAccountStore to get profile info (user id, email).
My problem is that the Facebook user account in iOS settings remains empty even after I login to Facebook using Facebook app.

My method only works if I manually login to Facebook **from iOS settings**. Does it mean that users of my app will need to login to Facebook in iOS settings as well?

Note: I am trying to avoid using Facebook SDK and just use the built-in `ACAccountStore` functions to authenticate with Facebook.

[image]

Comment: If you want to use ACAccountStore then the user must enter their Facebook credentials into settings. Simply logging in via the Facebook App won't set the system credentials.

Comment: Thanks, if you write it as an answer to my question I will mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `ACAccountStore` then the user must enter their Facebook credentials into settings. Simply logging in via the Facebook App won't set the system credentials.